# Install multiple iPhone apps at once from Xcode to device

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, build-automation

Supposing we have an Xcode iPhone project with 2 targets, is it possible to *build and install both of them on the device* with one click? Of course, I understand we will not be able to "build and run" both, but can we at least install them?

And to extend this concept a bit a bit: are there any scripts to achieve the same thing but with *multiple iPhone projects* instead of multiple targets in one project? This would be useful when you want to load all your apps on a new development device and don't want to go through all your projects one by one and install.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible at the same time. When Xcode installs an application the iDevice drops everything for 5-10 seconds and installs. I would simple just do them one by one as Xcode 4 has a ton of memory bugs regarding testing applications. When launching a test application and then exiting it a sigabrt occurs, I think the safest thing would just do individual installs.